# PHP Accessing emlelments of an array in a XML arrary retrieved with simplexml_load_file

Tags: php, xml, multidimensional-array

I am trying to print an element to this array (partial list below).  I am trying to retrieve the customSku element. I must not understand how to access this element, here is my print statement:

```
print $xml['Item'][0]['customSku'];
```

Here is the `print_r($xml);`:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object
(
    [@attributes] => Array
        (
            [count] => 190
            [offset] => 0
            [limit] => 100
        )

    [Item] => Array
        (
            [0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                (
                    [itemID] => 242
                    [systemSku] => 210000000242
                    [defaultCost] => 23.78
                    [avgCost] => 23.78
                    [tax] => true
                    [archived] => false
                    [itemType] => default
                    [description] => Springfield Offset Extension Post & Pin Stainless Steel - 13" 1610413-0SS
                    [modelYear] => 0
                    [upc] => 038132915572
                    [ean] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                        (
                        )

                    [customSku] => EB-5608042
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you post the XML file in question

Answer (score 1):

Using the `[]` operator is for accessing node attributes, which is not what you want in this case.

Try the following:

```
print $xml->Item[0]->customSku;
```

Comment: actually, $xml->Item[0]->customSku

Comment: @jnunn:  Only if there are multiple Item nodes you want to pick from. I'll add it for clarity, I suppose.

Comment: Agreed, just in his example there were multiple nodes.